# Spatial join many polygon layers and save ones with condition

Tags: qgis, python, spatial-join

I've got 8 polygon layers made from buffering point layers. All have `index` and `geometry` columns:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to select areas where at least 3 consecutive buffers intersect (like: buffer_03 & buffer_04 & buffer_05 & buffer_06).

I've got overall over 1 million points so trying to figure an effective way to process this (maybe Python code) as QGIS crashes while trying to Union the layers.

Comment: I think this should be handled by a **Postre/Postgis** database ... do u have any sample/sub-sample of your data to share if not confidential ?

Comment: Hi, good idea. Unfortunately I can't share the data, but as you can see from the images a simple case with computing problems. I would do union 8 times but it grows rapidly ...

Comment: are you able to aggregate these 8 layers in a postgis table, keeping an attribute to discriminate them and run an SQL query on this table ? is it time data ?

Comment: each layer is separate day, so there would be no problem adding them to postgis